# UIPresentationController passing touch event

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to do a custom notification view that slide up from the bottom to a certain height. I'm using a `UIPresentationController` but the problem is that touch events at the `ViewController` which present the VC are not detected when the Second VC is presented, is there a way to be able to do it?

[Here is a visual example of whats happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZNbb.png)

Comment: do you have written any code yet? if yes it would be cool to update your question with your existing solution / code

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well, after struggled a little I got the answer, what happened is that even if your `frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView` it's a little portion of the screen, the containerView's size of that frame is the whole window, so I just change the containerView's frame to be the same that `frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView` and now you can interact with both controllers, hope it helps someone. Here is an example:

```
    class AlertPresentationController: UIPresentationController {

    override var frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView: CGRect {
        guard let container = containerView else {
            fatalError("Error presenting Alert Controller")
        }
        let frameHeight: CGFloat = presentingViewController.view.frame.height * 0.2
        return CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: container.frame.width, height: frameHeight)
    }

    override func presentationTransitionWillBegin() {
        containerView?.frame = frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is a life saver

Comment: I could understand the concept of passing through touch event by reading this answer. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

If you want to access the presentingViewController objects you will have to dismiss the current controller first. You can do that by adding an `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your notificationController and dismiss the notification with that event.

Another possible approach is to implement your notification as an `UIView` instead of a `UIViewController` and to display it on your viewController's view directly, instead of adding another controller on top.

Comment: I know what you mean, I used to create those types of alert as UIView, but the thing is that I want to use that alert through all the ViewController in the app

Comment: Create a class like an `AlertFactory` that instantiates your Notifications and gives to any ViewController the possibility to create and display them. If all your ViewControllers will present the notifications in the same way, you can create an UIViewController extension to implement that and it will be accessible from any VC